# Exporting Animation with Mesh using Follow Path Constraint

Tags: animation, constraints

new to blender, was following a video tutorial which did not show me how to export the mesh/animations, and have run into some trouble. Project is a free designed Roller Coaster, created with 5 Objects.

One cube turned into tracks using an array modifier,
One cube turned into 3 Rail Car objects,
One Nurbs Path, used to create the "track"

### The issue:

Currently, when exported to FBX with animation keyframes, I can import to other software, however the animation does not come through. Furthermore, when reimporting into blender the entire mesh is gone.

[image]

Now, the object and animation work fine within blender, but something is going wrong during the export process. Would greatly love any hints/assistance, but unfortunately this is all the detail I can provide until asked other questions :)

Please just ask if you require more information. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Update -- I have managed to export the mesh into a file which can be remiported, however at this point it loses the follow path constraint entirely

Comment: You can't export constraints at all. Try to export to fbx. In the exporter window switch to the animation tab (in the lower left corner) and disable "All Actions" and "NLA Strips".